# fail to install ZMQ

Tags: node.js, npm, zeromq

i try to install ZMQ

my enveronment's version is

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm version
{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.29',
  v8: '3.14.5.9',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.27',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1h',
  npm: '1.4.14' }
```

---

I want to install zmq

so I type "npm install zmq"

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install zmq  
-  
> zmq@2.7.0 install C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\zmq  
> node-gyp rebuild  
\  
C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\zmq>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\  
npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild  
/MSBUILD : error MSB1009: 프로젝트 파일이 없습니다.  
스위치: build/binding.sln  
gyp ERR! build error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail  
ed with exit code: 1  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\  
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)  
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809: 12)  
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601  
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu  
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"  
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\zmq  
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29  
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1  
gyp ERR! not ok  
npm ERR! zmq@2.7.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`  
npm ERR! Exit status 1  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.7.0 install script.  
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,  
npm ERR! not with npm itself.  
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild  
npm ERR! You can get their info via:  
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq  
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.  
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601  
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod  
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "zmq"  
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32  
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29  
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:  
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log  
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

error MSB1009 means there is no project file

Visual Studio 2013 is installed

how do i fix this?

or how to install ZMQ for node js?

Comment: there's an open issue, https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/266

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution

"set PYTHON=C:\Python27\python.exe" will solves the problem